# Is there a way to select index of an array element on click?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, indexof

I'm struggling about selecting a particular index of an element inside an array on click. Here's that peace of code and thanks in advance!

```
<div>

 <span class="dot"></span>
 <span class="dot"></span> -- lets say we click on this span
 <span class="dot"></span>
 <span class="dot"></span>
 <span class="dot"></span>

</div>



var dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");
for(var i = 0; i < dots.length; i ++){
dots[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
console.log(this) -- prints the actual html <span class="dot"></span>

// ?? How to print index of an element? To be more specific, in this case 
just "1" ??

})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by adding a property (I named it *dotIndex*) to your *dots* and then console.log this property.

```
var dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");

for(var i = 0; i < dots.length; i ++){
    dots[i].dotIndex = i;
    dots[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(this.dotIndex);
    })
}
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/254uqtm0/

However, as Ori Drori suggested, you can just change **var** to **let** in your loop and it will work. If you are confused why, check this thread: [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: Be aware that when doing this, you’ll need to update the indexes if the number of dots change

Comment: Thank you all guys! And special thanks to you! Custom property didn't even crossed my mind. All the best! :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you add an event listener to each element, you can console.log the value of  `i`.

**Note:** I use `let i` and not `var i` inside the for loop because the `let` make `i` scoped to the blocked, and this preserves the current `i` value inside the event handler.

```js
const dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dot");
for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log({ i });
  })
}
```

```html
<div>

  <span class="dot">1</span>
  <span class="dot">2</span>
  <span class="dot">3</span>
  <span class="dot">4</span>
  <span class="dot">5</span>

</div>
```

Comment: You might want to explain that a crucial difference between your and the OP's code is the use of `let` not `var`, and why your answer will work only with the former.

Comment: Right you are @Utkanos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo need only one event listener ([event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)). The handler can iterate through the existing elements and do something with the index of it. Something like:

```js
const log = (...things) => { 
  console.clear(); 
  things.forEach(thing => console.log(thing))
};

// iterate within the handler
document.addEventListener("click", showIndex);

// alternative: add a dataset value to the elements on page load
// and make the handler do something with that. This is static and
// can't be used if the number of .dott-elements changes dynamcally
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dott")).forEach( (el, i) => el.dataset.index = i);
document.addEventListener("click", alternativeShowIndex);

function showIndex(evt) {
  if (evt.target.matches(".dot")) {
    let currentDot = {};
    const allDots = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dot"));
    for (let i = 0; i < allDots.length; i += 1) {
      if (allDots[i] === evt.target) {
        currentDot = {index: i, text: allDots[i].textContent};
        break;
      }
    }
    log(currentDot);
  }
}

function alternativeShowIndex(evt) {
  evt.target.matches(".dott") && log(evt.target.dataset.index);
}
```

```html
<div>
 <span class="dot">first</span>
 <span class="dot">second</span>
 <span class="dot">third</span>
 <span class="dot">fourth</span>
 <span class="dot">fifth</span>
</div>

<div>
 <span class="dott">alt-first</span>
 <span class="dott">alt-second</span>
 <span class="dott">alt-third</span>
 <span class="dott">alt-fourth</span>
 <span class="dott">alt-fifth</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `event.target.matches('.dot')` instead of `evt.target.classList.contains("dot")`.

Comment: @OriDrori Sure, changed it. Although `classList.contains` may be more self explanatory.

Comment: Whatever works for you. I prefer `matches` because it's useful to wider range of selector when using event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
const spans = [...document.getElementsByClassName('dot')];
spans.forEach(i => i.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(spans.indexOf(i))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
var dots = [...document.getElementsByClassName('dot')];

for (let i=0; i<dots.length; i++) {
 dots[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
   console.log(i);
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
   <span class="dot">0</span>
   <span class="dot">1</span> 
   <span class="dot">2</span>
   <span class="dot">3</span>
   <span class="dot">4</span>
</div>
```